# Creating a Class from a text document

Tags: c#-4.0

I am very, very new to programming and I'm currently trying to learn it as fast as I can as a requirement of my research. I am trying to create a class from a text document. I have produced the code below, however it is returning errors in when I debug which I am unsure of how to fix.

```
 List<Partitions> ListofPartitions = new List<Partitions>();
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Partitions.csv")
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    Partitions Pname = new Partitions(line);
                    Partitions Plength = new Partitions(line);
                    Partitions Pdepth = new Partitions(line);
                    Partitions Pheight = new Partitions(line);


                }
            }
            public class Partitions
            {
                string parameters;
                public int Pname;
                public double Plength;
                public double Pdepth;
                public double Pheight;
                public Partitions(string inputLine)
                {
                    parameters = inputLine;
                    string[]split = parameters.Split(',');
                    Pname = Convert.ToInt16(split[0]);
                    Plength = Convert.ToDouble(split[1]);
                    Pdepth = Convert.ToDouble(split[2]);
                    Pheight = Convert.ToDouble(split[3]);

                }
```

Returning errors:
GA.xaml.cs(39,24): error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'string'
GA.xaml.cs(39,45): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show your real code. This one makes no sense.

Comment: You forgot a semicolon on the second line. PS: please, always format your code and pose the questions more precisely.

Comment: Update: you also might want to wrap the second line with `using` block, so your `StreamReader` will properly dispose the underlying stream.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would bet it is

```
string[]split = ...
```

there should be space between [] and split like this

```
string[] split = ...
```

Comment: Why the downvote? That's what the error CS1525 says and the CS1003 can be the consequence of the first...

Comment: Because that's not true. In C# punctuators (e.g. [ ]) are valid separators. So `string[]split` is a perfectly valid expression. Also, see my comment to the original question.